# Play: What does adding a "many" object to a "one" list property do?

Tags: hibernate, playframework

This question probably has a lot to do with Hibernate, but since Play obfuscates Hibernate and i don't know it anyway...

Take the following sample code: User has many Posts.

```
public class User extends Model{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="author")
    public List<Post> posts;
}

public class Post extends Model{
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    public User author;
}
```

When I create a post `newPost` with the `User=John`, why do I have to call `John.add(newPost)`?

John and newPost are already in the database. Even without the `.add` call, the tables have foreign key restraints. What is actually happening when I call the `.add` method?

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on the code within the `.add` method. But with Hibernate you need to maintain both sides of the mapping in a bi-directional mapping.

So, your `add` method is likely to be adding the Post to the list of posts, so that both sides of the mapping are maintained (I am assuming when you created the Post you set the author at that point).

Comment: What I don't get is what that .add method does in terms of persistence. I looked what was generated by a test I wrote, and the database data didn't change whether I called .add or not. If I shut the application down and bring it back up (in prod), would the "1" side of the app know about all its "many" objects?